# Stellaris - How can I move my civilian (scientist) ships to other empires territory?

Tags: stellaris

So I got a quest in my 'situation log' and I have to move my scientist to inside of another civilizations border.

Apparently I cannot navigate my ships there regardless of I already had a deal with that civilization for open borders for civilian ships.

The game still tells me

**"We do not have border acces to.. xy"**

Is it a bug?

Comment: Sounds like it might be -- otherwise, perhaps the FTL drive of your ships are in need of upgrade, if they can't actually reach the space.

Comment: Did you check whether you actually have border access? Possibly you only gave border access to them or the system you want to go to is on a border and actually belongs to someone else.

Comment: What kind of FTL technology are you using? I believe you get that message if you can't actually get there, even if you have border access to the specific system.

Comment: How long ago did you have that deal?  By default you only get it for ten years.

Comment: All conditions are met. I have border access, I have 'path' with hyperspace travel to the destination system, I do have the access (I asked for 10 years and I tried right after) I don't know what what point I'm missing.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi A screenshot would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To move a ship to a system in another empire territory, you must have :

- Border access to their territory (military or civilian according to the type of the ship you want to move)
- Border access to all the empires for which you need to cross the territory to reach the system you want to acess
- A way to reach the system (hyperspace lane, system in range of your ship warp drive or your wormhole station, according to your FTL method)

If all of these points are met, you should be able to reach the system.

**Edit :**
As @DJ Pirtu said in a comment, going to war with an empire allows you to ignore the border access restrictions for this empire.

Comment: Also, being at war with an empire allows you to ignore the border access limitations of that empire. Propably not worth going to a war over just a quest, tough :)